# Rounded corner border in wxPython

Tags: python, swing, wxpython

Is there any way to design a rounded corner `TextCtrl` widget? Actually I am new to `wxPython` and I am used to `swing`.

Like in `swing`, is their any way in `wxPython` too to customize the border of the widgets?

Answer (score 0):

wxPython uses native widgets for the most part. If they don't have a rounded version, then the answer is No. However, wxPython supports custom widgets, so you could create your own text control with whatever features you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this hack

```
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0, 0, 50))
        
        ##This control will have round corners
        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self, size = (100, 50), pos = (50, 100), style = wx.NO_BORDER)
        self.text.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(222, 225, 234))
        
        ##This is to avoid sizers
        text2 = wx.TextCtrl(self, pos = (200, 100))
        
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        
    def OnPaint(self, event):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(wx.Colour(0, 0, 50)))
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(wx.Colour(222, 225, 234)))
        dc.DrawRoundedRectangle(self.text.GetPosition()[0] - 3, self.text.GetPosition()[1] - 3,
                                self.text.GetSize()[0] + 6, self.text.GetSize()[1] + 6, 5)
        
app = wx.App()
f = Frame()
f.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```